# VBA Access strange behavior with global variables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form that calls a series of reports, one after the other.  I also have a global variable that I use as a counter.  Every time a page's PageFooterSection_Format is called, I want to increment the count.  The problem is, the counter is counting higher that it should.  Here is my code:

I have a module called genericFunctions:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Public pageCount As Integer
```

In my form, I have a loop that calls this:

```
  'before loop
  pageCount = 1

  'start loop, which I left out for brevity

  'run in previewView first so page footer format function is called
  DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden, !ID
  'then run this to open in report view, so onload event runs
  DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewReport, , , acHidden, !ID
  'save report as a pdf
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, "PDF", rptPath
  'close report
  DoCmd.Close acReport, reportName

  'I then have a method that "stitches" these individual reports into one PDF
```

now, in my report, I have this code:

```
Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If (Report.CurrentView = 5) Then
        'a textbox in the report
        Me.pgNumber.Value = pageCount
        pageCount = pageCount + 1
    End If      
End Sub
```

I then place a breakpoint in the event.  This event is hit 3 times, as it should.  So, I would expect pgNumber text box to have 1,2,3 as their values but it has 2,4,6 instead.  No where else in my code do I increment the pageCount variable.  What's going on?  Is this a scope issue?

Comment: What does the pagecount variable show?

Comment: @JapanDave It shows the same as the the text  box, counting 2,4,6.  Could this be because I first open the report in acPreview then acReportView?  Even though the Format event is only hit when acPreview is called?

Comment: How about stepping through the code? It looks like it is running through the function twice???

Comment: Can you provide a full code block in form module so we can see this loop? Also, a Report's Print Preview should run OnLoad events, no reason for hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PageFooterSection_Format` runs both for `DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview` and for `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, "PDF"`, because the latter is like a print command.

In both cases, `Report.CurrentView = acViewReport` (5). I'm not sure what to make of that - it feels like a bug. (Note: this is Access 2010)

Anyway, since `DoCmd.OutputTo` is like a printing (and thus like a print preview), you can simply **omit this line**:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden, !ID
```

At least that worked for me.

---

Note: Breakpoints in event procedures can be misleading as to what happens when. It is safer to use `Debug.Print` calls.

My test code was:

```
Sub ReportTesting()

    Const reportName = "Bericht4"

    'before loop
    pageCount = 1

    'run in previewView first so page footer format function is called
    Debug.Print pageCount, "acViewPreview"
    DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden
    'then run this to open in report view, so onload event runs
    Debug.Print pageCount, "acViewReport"
    DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewReport, , , acHidden
    'save report as a pdf
    Debug.Print pageCount, "acOutputReport"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, "PDF", "C:\test.pdf"
    'close report
    DoCmd.Close acReport, reportName
    Debug.Print pageCount, "done"

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Debug.Print "Report View: " & Me.CurrentView

End Sub

Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    If Me.CurrentView = acViewReport Then
        Debug.Print "Footer - acViewReport"
        'a textbox in the report
        Me.pgNumber.Value = pageCount
        pageCount = pageCount + 1
    Else
        Debug.Print "Footer - other view"  ' <-- this never happens
    End If

End Sub
```

Output in Immediate window:

```
 1            acViewPreview
Report View: 5
Footer - acViewReport
 2            acViewReport
Report View: 6
 2            acOutputReport
Footer - acViewReport
 3            done
```

Comment: You're right.  That's so weird that, in acViewReport the event still gets called but the breakpoints do not work.  I wonder what other implications this will have?  Thanks for the help! +1 for running an experiment to confirm!